# Dynamic Average Calculations Against Partial Amounts of Distinct Groups

Tags: mysql

We have a table representing purchases of a particular SKU. Let's say it has 4 columns, PurchaseNo, SKU, QTY and PRICE.

The QTY column represents the number of an SKU involved in each particular purchase. The PRICE column represents the dollar value paid for each unit on that particular purchase.

We need a query to determine the average PRICE of all currently “in stock” AG1TBA.

Let us assume that the QTY currently in stock is **known to be** 200. Let's also assume the top 3 rows of this table have the following QTY and PRICE information: 50, 22 | 120, 21 | 96, 25 |.

Since we only have 200 in stock, we somehow need the query to calculate the average from all 50 (at $22), all 120 (at $21) and 30 of the 96 (at $25).  Obviously, the average price here is $21.85, but how could the query dynamically modify itself to limit the calculation of the average values to a specific amount of the the previous transactions (in this case, 200).

Here is an image of this hypothetical table:
[image: an image of this hypothetical table]

Comment: Why the newest PurchaseNo? I would expect to serve the older ones first: (5408, 50, 20), (5420, 100, 22) and (5429, 50 out of 96, 25).

Comment: Great question. That is because we are calculating these basically as FIFO rather than LIFO. If I have 200 in stock, then where did they come from? To us, they are the last 200 that we bought, because the other 216 units have necessarily been sold already, in previous transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the name of your table was `endurion`, you could solve it with following statements:

```
SET @stock := 200.0;
SET @amount := 0;

SELECT
    SUM(e1.costs)/@stock as average_price_per_unit
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        e.PurchaseNo,
        e.SKU,
        e.QTY,
        @amount := @amount + e.QTY,
        CASE 
            WHEN @amount <= @stock THEN e.QTY
            ELSE e.QTY + @stock - @amount
        END as part,
        e.PRICE,
        CASE 
            WHEN @amount <= @stock THEN e.QTY * e.PRICE
            ELSE (e.QTY + @stock - @amount) * e.PRICE
        END as costs
    FROM (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            endurion e1               -- replace your table name here
        WHERE
            SKU = 'AG1TBA'
        ORDER BY PurchaseNo DESC
    ) AS e    
    WHERE
        @amount <= @stock
) as e1;
```

**Explanation:**

The innermost Subselect

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    endurion e1
WHERE
    SKU = 'AG1TBA'
ORDER BY 
    PurchaseNo DESC
```

ensures we match the latest purchases, because as you stated those will give us the current stock.

The outermost query will give us the average price per unit in stock. That should be obvious.

The outer subquery calculates the total of units by purchases. If this is greater than the stock, then only a part contributes to the stock. This part is calculated in the case statement and the second one calculates the total price for this units.

**Hint**

The complete query works for my installation of MySQL v5.6.16 but not in the v5.5.32 of the [current sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9371ad/17). I would consider to insert the result of

```
SELECT 
    e.PurchaseNo,
    e.SKU,
    e.QTY,
    @amount := @amount + e.QTY,
    CASE 
        WHEN @amount <= @stock THEN e.QTY
        ELSE e.QTY + @stock - @amount
    END AS part,
    e.PRICE,
    CASE 
        WHEN @amount <= @stock THEN e.QTY * e.PRICE
        ELSE (e.QTY + @stock - @amount) * e.PRICE
    END AS costs
FROM (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        endurion e1               -- replace your table name here
    WHERE
        SKU = 'AG1TBA'
    ORDER BY PurchaseNo DESC
) AS e    
WHERE
    @amount <= @stock
```

into a temporary table and calculate the average by this temporary table.